# Why is __FILE__ and DOCUMENT_ROOT returning C:\path\to\webserver

Tags: apache, codeigniter, fuelcms

echoing out `__FILE__` *and* `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` on my Apache server is returning `string(26) "C:/Users/me/My Sites/pathtofile/"`.

What's up with that? It's being used in CodeIgniter a lot (and breaking them) as the files come out as:

```
<link href="C:/assets/css/main.css?c=" media="all" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I'm running Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) if that helps.

Comment: If you are trying to get web path of your css to load, you should use `echo base_url();` in CodeIgniter. `__FILE__` [PHP Document](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) is meant to give path of file location.

Comment: It's actually from the installation documents, a lot of links are like this.

Comment: _ _ FILE _ _ points to a directory? Really?

Comment: yeah, that's why i'm really confused?

Answer (score 0):

As Ariful mentioned, `__FILE__` is a constant set by PHP and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is an array of settings from the web server. These are used throughout CodeIgniter and FUEL CMS to handle file includes.

If you're looking to output a CSS path into your view, there is a helper that does exactly this:

```
echo css_path('main.css'); // outputs "http://example.com/assets/css/main.css"
```

More info about this and other asset helpers can be found here: http://docs.getfuelcms.com/helpers/asset_helper

Comment: the script is actually using a similar function and getting a result of "C:/assets/css/main.css", when i'm home i'll comment the exact function.. it's odd.